# Scanner Delimiters, Reg. Expression Problem

Tags: java, regex

I have a small Problem using reg. expressions with scanner

here's the code:

```
String name;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\s+|\\W+|\\_+");
    ArrayList<String> reay = new ArrayList<String>(1000);
    try {
        Scanner asdf = new Scanner(new File(s)).useDelimiter(p);
        while (asdf.hasNext()) {
            name = asdf.next();
            reay.add(name);

        }
        asdf.close();
    }
```

and the resulting array (using a lot of non-word chars in the text file):

```
[arst, , tdnxc, , rst, , arst, , arst, wfp, arst, , arst]
```

not sure what I'm missing and why I get whitespace entries in my array

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex matches one or more whitespaces, then OR one or more nonwords, then OR one or more underscores.

So for an input of " $_" it will say, space is a match!  Capture what's before next delimiter... $ is a match!  Return empty string between space and $.  Capture what's before next delimiter.. _ is a match!  return empty string between $ and _.

I think you meant for your delimiter to be:

```
[\\s\\W_]+
```

Comment: FYI, `\W` includes whitespace characters, so `[\s\W_]` can be written as `[\W_]` (`"[\\W_]"` in Java source code).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you use whitespace OR non-word characters OR underscores as delimiter. What shall happen if you e.g. have several of them mixed straight after one another?